# How to parse pdml xml file

Tags: xml, parsing

How to parse a similar XML file (this file is just the basic output) to get specific field values. For example the value and size from the field name "len"?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="pdml2html.xsl"?>
<!-- You can find pdml2html.xsl in /usr/share/wireshark or at http://anonsvn.wireshark.org/trunk/wireshark/pdml2html.xsl. -->
<pdml version="0" creator="wireshark/1.8.5" time="Sun May 10 00:54:17 2015" capture_file="">
<packet>
  <proto name="geninfo" pos="0" showname="General information" size="60">
    <field name="num" pos="0" show="3" showname="Number" value="3" size="60"/>
    <field name="len" pos="0" show="60" showname="Frame Length" value="3c" size="60"/>
  </proto>
</packet>
<packet>
  <proto name="geninfo" pos="0" showname="General information" size="95">
    <field name="num" pos="0" show="5" showname="Number" value="5" size="95"/>
    <field name="len" pos="0" show="95" showname="Frame Length" value="5f" size="95"/>
  </proto>
<packet>
```

Comment: What language / tool sets are you using?  There are lots out there.   What have you tried so far.  As it stands your question is very broad.

Comment: I tried SAX and DOM but it is either I did not know how to get specific fields with them or they don't read pdml XML file

Answer (score 0):

You can use serialize to get all the data

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            PDML pdml = new PDML()
            {
                packet = new List<Packet>(){
                    new Packet(){
                        proto = new Proto(){
                            name = "geninfo",
                            pos = 0,
                            showname = "General information",
                            size= 60,
                            field = new List<Field>(){
                                new Field(){
                                    name = "num",
                                    pos= 0,
                                    show = 3,
                                    showname = "Number", 
                                    value= "3",
                                    size = 60
                                },
                                new Field(){
                                    name= "len",
                                    pos= 0,
                                    show = 60,
                                    showname = "Frame Length",
                                    value = "3c",
                                    size = 60
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Packet(){
                        proto = new Proto(){
                            name = "geninfo",
                            pos = 0,
                            showname = "General information",
                            size = 95,
                            field = new List<Field>(){
                                new Field(){
                                    name= "num",
                                    pos = 0,
                                    show = 5,
                                    showname = "Number",
                                    value = "5",
                                    size = 95
                                },
                                new Field(){
                                    name = "len",
                                    pos = 0,
                                    show = 95,
                                    showname = "Frame Length",
                                    value = "5f",
                                    size = 95
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PDML));

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, pdml);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PDML));
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FILENAME);
            PDML newPDML = (PDML)xs.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
}

[XmlRoot("pdml")]
public class PDML
{
    [XmlElement("packet")]
    public List<Packet> packet {get;set;}
}
[XmlRoot("packet")]
public class Packet
{
    [XmlElement("proto")]
    public Proto proto { get; set; }
}
[XmlRoot("proto")]
public class Proto
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("pos")]
    public int pos { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("showname")]
    public string showname { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("size")]
    public int size { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("field")]
    public List<Field> field { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("field")]
public class Field
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("pos")]
    public int pos { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("show")]
    public int show { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("showname")]
    public string showname { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public string value { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("size")]
    public int size { get; set; }
}
​
```

Comment: I am not sure i pretty much understood what u meant. I already have the xml file available.

Comment: I like to write test data before attempting to read XML.  You can ignore the write XML and just use the read portion.  You can also verify my write XML matches your XML.